# I can not make my code iterate x -= 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, iteration, greatest-common-divisor

I am learning Python at MIT 6.00 and stacked making recursion code.
Only thing I want to do is just iterate deduct 1 from x, but don't know what to do..

Here is my code

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
    '''
    a, b: positive integers

    returns: a positive integer, the greatest common divisor of a & b.
    '''
    # Your code here
    x = min(a, b)
    if max(a, b) % min(a, b) == 0: 
        return x
    else:
        return #What comes to iterate -1 from x
```

Please help !!!

Comment: If we do x-1 from the else, how should that impact the a and b parameters?  You may want to re-evaluate your algorithm. For recursion the else will call the function again.

Comment: A side note: you don't need to take up five lines of comments after the `def gcdIter()` part; one line above the code definition is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is overly complicated, try this *recursive* implementation adapted from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations):

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a % b)
```

It seems that you were looking for an *iterative* solution (the question is misleading). If that was the case, here are a couple of possible implementations, also adapted from wikipedia:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def gcd(a, b):
    while a != b:
        if a > b:
            a -= b
        else:
            b -= a
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is like this

```
def gcd(a, b):
    #find the gcd of a,b,None if not found
    miner = min(a, b)
    gcd = None
    for i in xrange(1, miner+1):
        if(a % i == 0 and b % i == 0):
            gcd = i
    return gcd
```

now if a > b, you can get this from google
gcd(a,b) = gcd(a%b,b)
you can take a while loop to improve the performance of function, you can try it

Answer (score 0):

You guys are amazing!!!! Thanks for all the answers.
It turned out I needed to use While loop of minus 1 until the min(a, b) reach to gcd.

Though your answers seem much simpler, answer of this problem set is below

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
    '''
    a, b: positive integers

    returns: a positive integer, the greatest common divisor of a & b.
    '''
    x = min(a, b)

    # Keep looping until testValue divides both a & b evenly
    while a % x != 0 or b % x != 0:
        x -= 1

    return x
```

Again, thanks for all!!!

Comment: In your question, you stated that you were "stacked making recursion code". This is not recursive code, it's iterative!